# Object doesn't support property or method 'plot'

Tags: javascript

```
$(function() {
    var datatPie = [30,50];
    $.plot($(".target-sell"), datatPie,
    {
        series: {
            pie: {
                innerRadius: 0.6,
                show: true,
                label: {
                    show: false
                },
                stroke: {
                    width:.01,
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },

        colors: ["#ff6d60", "#cbcdd9"]
    });
```

the script is stopping by $.plot with Object doesn't support property or method 'plot' please need some advice. Thank you.

Comment: You need to make sure that `$.plot` is declared before you use it. Its stopping because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Well, it means what it says. The `plot` property doesn't exist in your `jQuery` object. I guess it's some kind of jQuery plugin? Maybe you didn't load it?

Comment: This is most likely the `flot` jQuery library. Check if it is loaded *after* the jQuery.js file.

Comment: This is in my script.js file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been "answered" by OP: turns out his input was wrong, so nothing related to actual coding.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the loading of the library is wrong, make sure you have something similar in your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure, that your custom script is after this in the markup, so jQuery and the plugin is also available for you (though I guess there is no problem with this, as it did find `$`, though maybe flot is loaded later than your custom script).

Comment: The site is www.tamnano.cz and it looks like its loading all.

Comment: I do not see either your script, neither the flot.js file

Comment: And where can I check where you use it? Its not on the main page.